# The `(not set)` data of `sessionGoogleAdsCampaignName` in Google Analytics 4 Data API disappeared

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) in [Python SDK 0.16.1](https://pypi.org/project/google-analytics-data/0.16.1/).

Use `run_report` to request report data with following `RunReportRequest`:

- property
- dimensions:

  - `sessionGoogleAdsKeyword`
  - `sessionGoogleAdsCampaignName`
- metrics:

  - `purchaseRevenue`
- date_ranges

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sessionGoogleAdsKeyword | sessionGoogleAdsCampaignName | purchaseRevenue |
| (not set) | B1 | 39591.30273 |
| aaa | A1 | 37742.99996 |
| ddd | A1 | 12957.99998 |
| (not set) | A3 | 5599.999996 |
| ccc | A1 | 1548.999987 |
| eee | A1 | 1429.999999 |
| bbb | A1 | 1260.000013 |
|  |  | (total) 100131.3027 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| sessionGoogleAdsKeyword |  | purchaseRevenue |
| (not set) |  | 370398.4939 |
| aaa |  | 37742.99996 |
| ddd |  | 12957.99998 |
| ccc |  | 1548.999987 |
| eee |  | 1429.999999 |
| bbb |  | 1260.000013 |
|  |  | (total) 425338.4939 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  | sessionGoogleAdsCampaignName | purchaseRevenue |
|  | A1 | 54939.99994 |
|  | B1 | 39591.30273 |
|  | A3 | 5599.999996 |
|  |  | (total) 100131.3027 |

I find that the `(not set)` data of `sessionGoogleAdsCampaignName` does not exist in the response.

I think the total of `purchaseRevenue` should be `425338.4939`.

Is it a bug?

Comment: I also came across this problem. I believe it's a bug on the side of Google Analytics reporting - both V3 and V4 (I tested both).
It's amazes me that there aren't many questions about it - and no answers at all! - as this is a very major bug. The whole value of GA is the collection and reporting of data, and here they are - omitting data from their responses.

I went through the documentations of both V3 and V4, and didn't find trace of the problem or solution.
The closest thing (which I also found in SO answers) is the flag `include_empty_rows`, but that solves a different problem.